# Python - How to get the article titles from either h2 or div tag in medium.com

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I am scraping medium.com. I have encountered a problem which is that some publications' article titles are in the `h2` tag whereas for some others it is in `div`. Now I am writing a function that takes in a link of the publication and returns the titles of articles in the page. I don't know which type I will be getting as an input. How should I tackle this?
[image] In this the article titles are in h2 tag.

[image] In this the article titles are in the div tag.

Both are from different publications.

Link for article titles in div tag: https://levelup.gitconnected.com

Link for article titles in h2 tag: https://towardsdatascience.com

Here is my code which works for the h2 tag

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time


options = Options()
options.add_argument("--headless")
options.add_argument('--log-level=3')
options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)

class Publication:
    def __init__(self, link):
        self.link = link

    def get_articles(self):
        "Get the articles of the user/publication which was given as input"
        link = self.link
        driver.get(link)
        scroll_pause = 0.5
        # Get scroll height
        last_height = driver.execute_script("return document.documentElement.scrollHeight")
        run_time, max_run_time = 0, 1
        while True:
            iteration_start = time.time()
            # Scroll down to bottom
            driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, 1000*document.documentElement.scrollHeight);")

            # Wait to load page
            time.sleep(scroll_pause)

            # Calculate new scroll height and compare with last scroll height
            new_height = driver.execute_script("return document.documentElement.scrollHeight")
            scrolled = new_height != last_height
            timed_out = run_time >= max_run_time
            if scrolled:
                run_time = 0
                last_height = new_height
            elif not scrolled and not timed_out:
                run_time += time.time() - iteration_start
            elif not scrolled and timed_out:
                break
        elements = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "h2")
        for x in elements:
            print(x.text)
```

Comment: Example of a _**link**_?

Comment: I have edited the question. Please take a look @undetectedSelenium

Comment: Can you elaborate in which cases you get the articles in `<h2>` and in which cases you get the articles in `<div>`? Example urls please?

Comment: Added the link please check

Comment: Considering the two different links [link A](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/) and [link B](https://towardsdatascience.com/) the HTML elements would be different. Any reason you expect them to be similar? How is this issue connected to medium.com?

Comment: They are both publications of medium.com I am creating a function that when called by passing a link should be able to get the article names on that page.

Comment: I'm still not sure why you expect the elements of two different websites to be similar?

Comment: I mean they are from the same website. That is why.  Should I change my approach?

Comment: @KarthikBhandary, As you say both the websites are publications of medium.com but ultimately they are two different URLs. So you should parse/find them differently. One way can be to put a check in place for the URL and based on that parse or find the element accordingly.

Comment: What I have done is that I created a separate function for list type format and a separate one for the grid type.

Comment: Why don't you write 2 separate functions for each (obviously different) website, in an if/else control flow?

Comment: I did just that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one way of getting both `h2` and `h3` titles from those two websites:

```
[...]
elements = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//h2 | //h3")
[...]
```

A better way would be to `wait` for those elements to be fully loaded in page, by using [Selenium waits](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/waits/).

Comment: Hey, @BarrythePlatipus Can you help me with this one? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76515904/selenium-getting-the-text-in-span-tag