# Selenium - Getting the Text in span tag

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I am trying to get the followers count from Instagram. I am using selenium to do the task. Now the structure in which the followers is as follows(This is just to give you an idea. Please check the Instagram website using inspect tool)

```
[...]
<span class="_ac2a">
<span> 216 </span>
</span>
[...]
```

The above is the rough structure. I want `216`. When I try the following code I get `[]` as the result
The code:

```
        username = self.username
        driver.get(f"https://www.instagram.com/{username}/")
        try:
            #html = self.__scrape_page()
            #page = self.__parse_page(html)

            #followers = page.find_all("meta", attrs={"name": "description"})
            followers = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//span[@class="_ac2a"]/span')
            return followers
        #     followers_count = (followers[0]["content"].split(",")[0].split(" ")[0])
        #     return {
        #         "data": followers_count,
        #         "message": f"Followers found for user {self.username}",
        #     }
        except Exception as e:
            message = f"{self.username} not found!"
            return {"data": None, "message": message}
```

How do I get the followers?

Comment: really? Im getting `[]` what is the output you are getting? @Alexander

Comment: I am getting a list with 3 WebElements inside of it.

Comment: Are you getting the follower count? That is what we want. Try printing the web elements using .text

Comment: yes I am getting it

Comment: I'm not getting it though! Why is that?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254212/discussion-between-alexander-and-karthik-bhandary).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, I personally think that the best way to extract the followers count for a specific Instagram account would be from the Meta Data section in the HTML.

Here is how you would accomplish this using `selenium`

```
import re as regex
from time import sleep
from selenium import webdriver
import selenium.common.exceptions
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-infobars")
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-popup-blocking")
chrome_options.add_argument('--ignore-ssl-errors')
chrome_options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')

# disable the banner "Chrome is being controlled by automated test software"
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("useAutomationExtension", False)
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ['enable-automation'])

driver=webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='/usr/local/bin/chromedriver',options=chrome_options)

driver.get('https://www.instagram.com/therock/')
try:
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 60)
    account_description_content = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//meta[@name='description']").get_attribute("content")
    account_description_results = regex.split(', |-', account_description_content)
    print('Instagram Account:', account_description_results[3].split('from')[1])
    print('Number of Followers:', account_description_results[0].strip('Followers'))
    print('Number of Following:', account_description_results[1].strip('Following'))
    print('Number of Posts:', account_description_results[2].strip('Posts'))

except selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException as e:
    print(e)

finally:
    driver.quit()
```

This outputs this:

```
Instagram Account:  Dwayne Johnson (@therock)
Number of Followers: 386M 
Number of Following: 704 
Number of Posts: 7,322 Posts
```

After reviewing your code again, I noticed a small error in this line: `followers = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//span[@class="_ac2a"]/span`

If you still want to use a SPAN Class try the code below.

*Please note that if Instagram changes the variable `_ac2a` name the code below will have to be updated with the new naming convention. The META extraction method likely will not be need to updated.*

```
from time import sleep
from selenium import webdriver
import selenium.common.exceptions
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-infobars")
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-popup-blocking")
chrome_options.add_argument('--ignore-ssl-errors')
chrome_options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')

# disable the banner "Chrome is being controlled by automated test software"
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("useAutomationExtension", False)
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ['enable-automation'])

driver=webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='/usr/local/bin/chromedriver',options=chrome_options)

driver.get('https://www.instagram.com/therock/')
try:
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 60)
    account_details = wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, '//span[@class="_ac2a"]')))
    print('Number of Posts:', account_details[0].text)
    print('Number of Followers:', account_details[1].text)
    print('Number of Following:', account_details[2].text)

except selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException as e:
    print(e)

finally:
    driver.quit()
```

This outputs this:

```
Number of Posts: 7,320
Number of Followers: 385M
Number of Following: 696
```

Comment: Hey, it is showing page not found! When Im running the code!

Comment: Page is not available it is saying! It worked when I ran it for the first time!

Comment: For some reason, It only works once (cleared the cache), and then when I run it again it is showing Page is not available.

Comment: @KarthikBhandary Which one of the answers gives page not found?

Comment: Both of them. But when I ran the code which uses span. It worked fine for the first time. It started giving that from the second time I ran the code.

Comment: Currently both these answers work on my system. I added some WebDriverWait code to both answers.  You might need to increase the wait time so that the fully page loads.  Let me know what happens with the updated wait code, which can be increased for your environment.

Comment: I don't think it is the problem with the page not loading. It is not able to get the Instagram profile for some reason.

Comment: are you using the same profile as my answer?

Comment: yes, it's the same. I tried with 'https://www.instagram.com/therock' and with this f"https://www.instagram.com{username}" as well.

Comment: Does this load correctly `https://www.instagram.com/therock` in your Chrome browser?

Comment: No its not loading

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254233/discussion-between-life-is-complex-and-karthik-bhandary).